# retrieve all data in list instead of one specific item in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have use db first approach for my project. I have created SQL server db and created ADO.net model. In data model,there are few tables namely service_provider,picture,comment. I have created viewmodel for display data in single view. Below I have given my Controller method foe retrieve specific profile.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    List<ImageData> details = new List<ImageData>();
    var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                      join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                      join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                      select new { s.SPID,s.Sp_name, s.Sp_location,s.Sp_description, s.Sp_rate, s.service_type, c.Cityname, p.pic });

    foreach (var item in sp_details)
    {
        ImageData SpView = new ImageData(); // ViewModel
        SpView.Sp_name = item.Sp_name;
        SpView.Sp_location = item.Sp_location;
        SpView.Cityname = item.Cityname;
        SpView.Sp_rate = item.Sp_rate;
        SpView.pic = item.pic;

        if (SpView.SPID == id)
        {
            details.Add(SpView);
        }
    }

    if (details == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(details);
}
```

here is my View

```
@model List<WEB1.ViewModel.ImageData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<div class="span9">
    <div class="itembody">
        <div class="itemprofile">

            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {

                <p class="name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_name)</p>
                <p class="cattype">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_location)</p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Place Type</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cnt_type)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Opening Hours</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cnt_wh)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_description)</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Rate</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_rate)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

above code display all the data in list.but I want to display only one profile where *SPID* == *id*. can somebody help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Just use a `where` clause in your query and then `.FirstOrDefault()` to return a single item (the view needs to be `@model WEB1.ViewModel.ImageData` and no loop.

Comment: use `where` clause before `select` statement like   `where s.Id == id` , this will bring you record with service_provider id is selected id If the Id number is unique, it will bring only 1 result with type of `IQueryable<'a>`  that way you wouldn't have to change any of your code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have done.but it makes error in foreach loop in controller like *foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type *

Comment: I said to delete the `foreach` statements (`.FirstOfDefault()` returns one item, not a collection)

Comment: I have removed it agian get error in`SpView.Sp_name = item.Sp_name;` what sholud I write instead of *item* in code

Comment: Use `select new ImageData() { Sp_name = s.Sp_name, Sp_location = s.Sp_location, ...` etc

Comment: it makes error like *cannot initialize type  with a collection initializer because it does not implement*

Comment: this is my ViewModel`public class ImageData
    {
        public int SPID { get; set; }
        public string Sp_email { get; set; }
        public string Sp_password { get; set; }
        public string Sp_name { get; set; }
        public string Sp_location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> City_ID { get; set; }
        public string Company_type { get; set; }
        public string Sp_description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Sp_rate { get; set;}
        public byte[] pic { get; set; } public string Cityname { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: change linq query like this...'var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
     where s.spid = id
                          select new { s.SPID,s.Sp_name, s.Sp_location,s.Sp_description, s.Sp_rate, s.service_type, c.Cityname, p.pic });'

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`8[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Double],System.String,System.String,System.Byte[]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WEB1.ViewModel.ImageData'.  error has come

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.  Filter your select, then it will return the item you want to display.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            List<ImageData> details = new List<ImageData>();
            var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                              join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                              join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                              where s.SPID == id
                              select new { s.SPID,s.Sp_name, s.Sp_location,s.Sp_description, s.Sp_rate, s.service_type, c.Cityname, p.pic });
```